# PowerShell - regex to get string between two strings

Tags: regex, string, powershell, special-characters

I'm not very experienced in Regex. Can you tell me how to get a string value from between two strings?

The subject will always be in this format : `//subject/some_other_stuff`

I need to get the string found between `//` and `/`.

For example:

Full String = `//Manhattan/Project`

Output = `Manhattan`

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a negated character class and reference capturing group `#1` for your match result.

```
//([^/]+)/
```

Explanation:

```
//         # '//'
(          # group and capture to \1:
  [^/]+    #   any character except: '/' (1 or more times)
)          # end of \1
/          # '/'
```

Comment: Quick and easy. Thank you! Appreciate the explanation too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the below regex which uses lookarounds.

```
(?<=\/\/)[^\/]+(?=\/)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the strings are always of the same format, you can simply split them on `/` and then retrieve the element at index 2 (the third element):

```
PS > $str = "//Manhattan/Project"
PS > $str.split('/')[2]
Manhattan
PS > $str = "//subject/some_other_stuff"
PS > $str.split('/')[2]
subject
PS >
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't even know you could retrieve a particular element like that.